# libGdx Box2d Sword

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Is there a good way to use libGdx Box2D as the main library for a rogue-like game? I want so items could be picked, dropped, and when they are picked to be a separate part of character (I  tried joints but it doesn't look good because it moves with the character)

Comment: Can you show the behaviour you currently get with joints, and explain how that differs from what you want in more detail? How should the item move instead?